pyAudioAnalysis speaker_diarization doesn't work well
I can play test.wav with ffplay and other media players.
Why doesn't speaker_diarization work well in my code, and how to solve this problem?
from unittest import result
import numpy as np
import librosa
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pyAudioAnalysis import audioSegmentation as aS

audio_file_path = "G:\\Project\\Nunu\\duet\\test.wav"

signal, sample_rate = librosa.load(audio_file_path, sr=None)

print(f"Sample Rate: {sample_rate}, Signal Shape: {signal.shape}")

segments, labels, unused = aS.speaker_diarization(audio_file_path, n_speakers=2)  # n_speakers=0 自动识别

print(f"Segments: {segments}")
print(f"Labels: {labels}")

This gives the following output:
Sample Rate: 44100, Signal Shape: (1299867,)
Segments: [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
Labels: -1


What do you mean exactly with "does not work well?"
